# Get the hours of a timestamp and display in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

For my Grafana panel i would like to extract and display the hours of a date from a given timestamp series

For example the timestamp 1628274040 which is 2021-08-06 18:20:40 (CET) i would like to only have "18:20:40" and display this comparable in my panel (display as graph).

How to do that? The underlying data is influxDB and the query is influxQL. I searched the grafana dashboard for converting function but dont find any.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand how you imagine to present this data in  Grafan graph panel.
But I know that there is possibility to make it as a table with [Datatable Panel Plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/briangann-datatable-panel/) by setting "Column Style" of "Time" as "HH:mm:ss".
It will allow you to present your data as a table with format exactly as you described.
[Realisation example - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxWks.png)

Comment: I would like to present the data on y-axis as range from 0.00AM to 23.59PM ... the hours and minutes are a bit different every day and i would like to make that little fluctuation visible

Answer (score 0):

This will return current date, like "24/05/22":
${__to:date:DD/MM/WW}

This will return Timestamp from today date, like "1653447599999":
${__to}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).